# simple vs simple hypothesis, finding sample size given type 1 and 2 error probabilities

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size, type-i-and-ii-errors

The problem is:

It is decided to investigate the hypotheses H0 : μ = €678 and H1 : μ = €720.
Assuming that the prices are normally distributed with standard deviation €100, what sample size must be tested so that the probabilities of making a type I and type II error are 5% and 10%, respectively?

So, i have no idea how to solve it. I need to find a sample size but how can i do it in case of simple vs simple hypothesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various calculators  (depending on the assumption of the distribution of both classes) to help [calculate the sample size for a hypothesis test](https://www.stat.ubc.ca/%7Erollin/stats/ssize/n2.html). Given those parameters, the sample size for a 1-sided test is 98.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! As i understand the formula used here is: $n=\frac{\sigma^{2}\left(z_{1-\beta}+z_{1-\alpha}\right)^{2}}{\left(\mu_{0}-\mu_{1}\right)^{2}}$ But using this formula the required sample size is 48, not 98. I cannot figure out why im getting different result. It must be that calculator uses different formula or i messed up with calculations but it seems right: $n=\frac{\ 100^{2}\left(1.282+1.645\right)^{2}}{\left(720-678\right)^{2}}$
 Would you be able to clarify it a little bit?

Comment: The discrepancy may come from whether this is a one-sample or two-sample test. The latter will introduce a factor of 2 to the RHS of the formula quoted by @Avrg_economics_student (as $\sigma^2$ will now be $100^2 + 100^2 = 2 \times 100^2$).

Comment: @B.Liu Thank you! It seems right, the calculator assumes two sample test, when in fact a one sample test would be correct.